# Control Manipulate variables inside Manipulate

Tags: manipulate

I have the data for graph nodes as:

```
graphComponents = {{"blood", "pressur"}, {"harvard", "oxford"}, {"help",  "lower"},
{"oxford", "benefit"}, {"harvard", "benefit"}, {"lower",  "level"}, {"faceoff", "benefit"}
, {"oxford", "faceoff"}, {"harvard", "faceoff"}, {"over", "benefit"}, {"faceoff", "over"},
{"oxford", "over"}, {"harvard", "over"}, {"benefit", "drug"}, 
{"oxford",  "drug"}, {"harvard", "drug"}, {"faceoff", "drug"}, {"fast",  "test"},
{"over", "drug"}, {"test", "test2"}};
```

Then I want to make a `Manipulate` to show the communities of the graph:

```
Manipulate[
  components = graphComponents[[1 ;; L]];
  rawGraph = Graph[#[[1]] <-> #[[2]] & /@ graphComponents[[1 ;; L]]];
  communities = FindGraphCommunities[rawGraph];
  H = HighlightGraph[rawGraph, Subgraph[rawGraph, communities[[i]]]],
  {{L, 15, "Number of Tuples: "}, 5, 20, 5}, 
  {{i, 2, "Cluster number: "}, 1, 3, 1}, 
  LocalizeVariables -> False]
```

The question is as the value of `L` changes the number of communities change as well. So the control list for variable `i` should be updated when `L` changes. How should this be done?

Comment: Please consider giving a minimal working example. I'm sure `graphComponents` can be reduced to a few words.

Comment: As I need to show the number of communities changing,  19 is the minimum to have three possible outcomes!

Comment: The less code there is, the better it is :)

Comment: Please don't provide a code that produces endless errors.. :)

Comment: Corrected.... Thanks

Comment: Can you just provide the output given by `FindGraphCommunities[rawGraph]`? For users (like me :P) using a version of _Mathematica_ < 9.

Comment: This generates a nested list of the nodes. As sample for `L=5` This looks like `{{"harvard", "oxford", "benefit"}, {"blood", "pressur"}, {"help", "lower"}}`

Comment: Can you give it for `L=10`? So one can use `Manipulate` :)

Comment: `L=10` then `{{"harvard", "oxford", "benefit", "faceoff", "over"}, {"help", "lower", "level"}, {"blood", "pressur"}}` and `L=20` then `{{"harvard", "oxford", "benefit", "faceoff", "over", "drug"}, {"help", "lower", "level"}, {"fast", "test", "test2"}, {"blood", "pressur"}}`

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want?

```
graphComponents = 
  {{"blood", "pressur"}, {"harvard", "oxford"}, {"help", "lower"}, {"oxford", "benefit"}, 
   {"harvard", "benefit"}, {"lower", "level"}, {"faceoff", "benefit"}, {"oxford", "faceoff"}, 
   {"harvard", "faceoff"}, {"over", "benefit"}, {"faceoff", "over"}, {"oxford", "over"}, 
   {"harvard", "over"}, {"benefit", "drug"}, {"oxford", "drug"}, {"harvard", "drug"}, 
   {"faceoff", "drug"}, {"fast", "test"}, {"over", "drug"}, {"test", "test2"}};
com =
  {{{"harvard", "oxford", "benefit"}, {"blood", "pressur"}, {"help", "lower"}}, 
   {{"harvard", "oxford", "benefit","faceoff", "over"}, {"help", "lower", "level"}, {"blood", "pressur"}}, 
   {{"harvard", "oxford", "benefit", "faceoff", "over", "drug"}, {"help", "lower", "level"}, {"fast", "test", "test2"}, {"blood", "pressur"}}};

Manipulate[HighlightGraph[rawGraph[L], Subgraph[rawGraph[L], com[[i]]]], 
  {{L, 20, "Number of Tuples: "}, {5, 10, 20}}, {{i, 2, "Cluster number: "}, 1, 3, 1}, 
  Initialization :> 
    (rawGraph[n_] := Graph[#[[1]] <-> #[[2]] & /@ graphComponents[[1 ;; n]]];)]
```

[image]

Comment: This is not good as I cannot generate the com object for huge list of elements!

Comment: @Morry Well, `com = FindGraphCommunities[rawGraph[#]]&/@{5,10,20};`. Put it in where ever you want.

Comment: The fact is I have a huge data and the L may have many possibilities.... This is going to be a function...I do not want the to compute com for every possibility!

Answer (score 2):

You could use Dynamic to update i:

```
graphComponents = {{"blood", "pressur"}, {"harvard", 
    "oxford"}, {"help", "lower"}, {"oxford", "benefit"}, {"harvard", 
    "benefit"}, {"lower", "level"}, {"faceoff", "benefit"}, {"oxford",
     "faceoff"}, {"harvard", "faceoff"}, {"over", 
    "benefit"}, {"faceoff", "over"}, {"oxford", "over"}, {"harvard", 
    "over"}, {"benefit", "drug"}, {"oxford", "drug"}, {"harvard", 
    "drug"}, {"faceoff", "drug"}, {"fast", "test"}, {"over", 
    "drug"}, {"test", "test2"}};

l = 3;
Manipulate[components = graphComponents[[1 ;; L]];
 rawGraph = Graph[#[[1]] <-> #[[2]] & /@ graphComponents[[1 ;; L]]];
 communities = FindGraphCommunities[rawGraph];
 l = Length[communities];
 i = Min[l, i];
 H = HighlightGraph[rawGraph, 
   Subgraph[rawGraph, communities[[i]]]], {{L, 15, 
   "Number of Tuples: "}, 5, 20, 5}, {{i, 2, "Cluster number: "}, 1, 
  Dynamic[l], 1}, LocalizeVariables -> False]
```